# Why is iteration not a basic construct of control flows?

Tags: iteration, workflow, control-flow

According to my textbook,

> Iteration is not a basic construct: it can be expressed in terms of "selection of choice".

Could anyone show me how to express iteration by selection of choice?

Comment: Would it not be just be "[A: ..] <B if X goto A>"?